# This website does not have permission to use the Geolocation API

Tags: internet-explorer, geolocation

I am expericing this error, while trying to use the geolocation api:

```
This website does not have permission to use the Geolocation API
```

The strange thing is that the same website is running fine on one some systems(where **IE.9 and I.E10** are installed) and it throws error on a system where **I.E 9** is installed.

We tested it on different systems but it throws error only on that particular system where **I.E9** is installed.

- Do we need some browser settings to use this API?
- What persmission do we require for our website, to use the geolocation API?

**Code**:

```
function geolocateUser()
{
    // If the browser supports the Geolocation API
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
    }
    else {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
    }

}
```

In case of success:

```
function geolocationSuccess(position) {

    var userCurrentLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);



}
```

In case of error:

```
function geolocationError(positionError) {

    alert(positionError.message + "\n" + "you will be redirected to default location.");


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions below for IE:

- Open Tools>> Internet Options >> see below image

[image]

Comment: It doesnt help. I have this in console.log `PositionError {}code: 1message: "User denied Geolocation"__proto__: PositionError
HTMLPage1.html:88 This website does not have permission to use the Geolocation API`

Answer (score 7):

This could be a Windows setting, at least it was in my case. Try going to Settings (search from the Start menu in Windows) > Privacy > Location and turn Location = On.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 you may need to turn on "Location service" in Settings > Privacy > Location before you turn it on in Internet Explorer.

See: [Windows 10 location service and privacy](https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-10-location-and-privacy)

Answer (score -1):

Do note that if you get this problem in windows phone while developing mobile apps, the website should be something like: "`http://www.geo.com/geo`". If the domain is a certain ip address, say: "`192.168.1.2`", ie "`http://192.168.1.2/geo`", you can never get through it!